# how to secure base URL or secure string using pro guard?

Tags: android, api, android-proguard, base-url

```
@Override

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{

super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

 Utils.HOST_URL = "http://......";
}
```

how to secure my host URL using pro guard or any other method?

Answer (score -1):

yes you can.open build.gradle(Module:App) and enter your url here

```
buildTypes {
        debug {
         buildConfigField("String","GO","URL");
        }
        release {
            buildConfigField("String","GO","URL");
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
```

and get your url on code `BuildConfig.GO`

Comment: if i decomplie then show me url in buildconfig file

Comment: same problem i m also facing